# CSS isn't showing up

Tags: css

When I do the CTRL click in both visual studio and chrome console, the link goes to the right stylesheet so I know the link is right but for some reason it doesn't show in the console under "sources", only the index and js. Its not loading any of the CSS either. No idea why.

```
<head>
<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<script src='javascript.js' defer></script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Is `stylesheet.css` at the same level as `javascript.js` in your file structure? As in it's not nested in another directory/folder.

Comment: yea its in the same foldre

Answer (score 0):

As long as the stylesheet is in the same folder as this HTML file, you'll want to change your `<link`> tag to read: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">` (Source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)